Should we require acronyms to be defined?
I recently commented on a neuroscience question requesting:

for the benefit of others who may not know, can you please define any acronyms uncommon outside of the field of study such as CNS?

I am not necessarily looking for strictness on requirements. Here are a couple of examples of what I'm talking about.

IQ is mentioned a lot outside the fields of psychology and neuroscience and everyone knows IQ refers to intelligence ... although ... should IQ be defined as Intelligence Quotient?

I know that CNS is Central Nervous System. But, could that be the correct definition for the acronym used? Being that I am not in the field of neuroscience, is there another definition I am not aware of?



IQ should not be clarified imo, but CNS is a step too far; that should be written out in full I guess. For folks into Neurosci, like me, CNS is obvious, but for someone into Clinical Psychology, it may not.  IQ, on the other hand, is often used in common language as well.

That's my thinking @AliceD
